# Tkinter -exporting data real time

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry. Only my 3rd week in Python. I am creating a simple tkinter GUI with a button which returns the value of 1 when pressed. How would i  be able to embed it in a while loop, so that would count real time how many times the button was pressed?

```py
from tkinter import *

class Event:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rok=Tk()
        self.rok.geometry('+50+400')

        Button(self.rok,text='Click Me',command=self.click).grid(row=0)
        Button(self.rok,text='Quit',command=self.quit).grid(row=1)

        self.rok.mainloop()

    def click(self):
        self.a=1
        return self.a

    def quit(self):
        self.rok.destroy()

x=(Event().click())
```

Comment: You *can't* embed Tkinter code in a loop, because for the duration that your loop is running,Tkinter's  mainloop *isn't* running, and no events (such as clicks on the button) can be processed.  What you need to do is increment a counter, and possibly update a display of that counter, from within your `click()` function - no loop needed.  (Note that returning anything from that function is pointless, when Tkinter calls it in response to a click it does nothing with that value.)

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestion within the function.